# eclipse xml editor inserts tabs for spaces

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor

I find that the Eclipse `XML` editor always inserts tabs for spaces even if you have the "Insert spaces for tabs" option checked under `Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors`.

You can open any `XML` file, and then do `CTRL-SHIFT-F` to format the file and you'll see this behavior (all your spaces will be replaced with tabs where appropriate).

I noticed this behavior with Ganymede, and just upgraded to Galileo today and was hoping it was fixed, but it seems to be the same.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Go to **Windows > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor** and select **Indent using spaces**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pascal, as usual, your advice is spot on :)

Comment: I was going to say this didn't work for me (I had both options Insert spaces for tabs and Indent using spaces set), but it turns out I'm using the Ant file editor, which does not inherit from the XML editor. In the Ant editor, the option to set is Windows > Preferences > Ant > Editor > Formatter > [uncheck] Use tab character instead of spaces.

Comment: Just a heads-up for anyone who finds this, hoping for it to take effect when editing Android XML files ... this setting is ignored by default.  To get the Android XML editor to recognize default Eclipse XML settings, see this http://tools.android.com/recent/xmlformatter. (late 2011)

Comment: For Maven `pom.xml`s, the answer is in the question (`General / Editors / Text Editors / Insert spaces for tabs`).

Comment: make sure file is opened with xml editor by right click -> open with -> XML Editor

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about this issue with the XML editor specifically, but I use the [AnyEdit tools plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) to handle any tabs/spaces issues.

Once you've installed the plugin go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> AnyEdit Tools and you can enable auto conversion of tabs to spaces (or vice versa) whenever you save a file.  I find this very useful because it will also fix any files you've accidentally inserted tabs into when you change those files.

This plugin also provides a nice set text functions to use in the 'Convert' section of the right click menu of any text editor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

### Steps:

- Open `Eclipse -> Preferences`
- Go to `XML -> XML Files -> Editor`
- Select the `Indent using spaces` option

[image]

Comment: It's a bit late, but you can improve your answer by providing text steps.

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to this issue, if you do a multi-line indentation in an XML editor, you are out of luck (you'll get tabs):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168988

(Reported bug in Eclipse, but marked as WON'T FIX)

Comment: isn't that bug about PDTs PHP editor, not about core eclipse xml editor